# Construction of a partition of unity on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces

The setting is the following:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, define the sets 
$$\Omega_m =\{ x \in \Omega : |x| < m \text{ and } dist(x, \partial\Omega) > \frac{1}{m}\} $$
and set $\Omega_0 = \emptyset$ and define $U_m := \Omega_{m+1} \setminus \overline{\Omega_{m-1}}$. We then have that $\Omega = \cup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} U_m$ is an open covering of $\Omega$.

Now how does one choose (or **construct**) a $C^\infty$ locally finite partition of unity $(\phi_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \subset C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\text{supp}(\phi_m) \subset U_m$, $0 \leq \psi_m \leq 1$ and $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}}\phi_m = 1$?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you looked in a differential geometry/topology book for a general construction? The particular details of your cover are unimportant; all that matters is that you have an open covering of a smooth manifold.

Comment: I am not really familiar with manifolds, so a differential geometry book would probably not fit me.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you would typically find in the very early sections of such a book, so it shouldn't be much of a barrier to entry.